# Create relation with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got some pain with a python script that should insert data in an existing database.
Here is my issue (without all the complexity :) )

My database contain many table here i'm interested with 4 of them. They are also used by a django app but here i'm just doing python scripting. Here is a simplify model.py

model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class TService(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class TLocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class TStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class LServicehasstatus(models.Model):
     t_service_idservice = models.ForeignKey('TService', db_column='T_Service_idService', blank=True, null=True) 
     t_status_idstatus = models.ForeignKey('TStatus', db_column='T_Status_idStatus', blank=True, null=True) 
     t_location_idlocation = models.ForeignKey('TLocation', db_column='T_Location_idLocation', blank=True, null=True)
```

So there is a relation between Location, Service and status

I'm trying to fill this LServicehasstatus table with a python script using SQLAlchemy.
I can parse and retrieve everything but not insert data.

script :

```
Base = automap_base()

    engine = create_engine('mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = Session()

    Location = Base.classes.common_tlocation
    Services = Base.classes.common_tservice
    Status = Base.classes.common_tstatus

#Not working
    statusupdate = Servicehasstatus(\
        Servicehasstatus.T_Service_idService=="2",\
        Servicehasstatus.T_Host_idLocation=="1",\
        Servicehasstatus.T_Status_idStatus=="1")
    session.add(statusupdate)
    session.commit()
```

The error is :

```
ERROR: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

I think my method is not good i cant give the foreign key directly, i think i should map existing object to it but i really can't figure out how.

Thanks for you very much for your help,

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not with any relationship, but with how you are calling `Servicehasstatus()`.  The default constructor takes keyword args and assigns them to attrs.  The line should look like this:

```
statusupdate = Servicehasstatus(
    T_Service_idService=2,
    T_Host_idLocation=1,
    T_Status_idStatus=1
)
```

The error is a standard Python `TypeError`, although it is a little cryptic.  All it means is that the `__init__` method of the class takes 1 positional argument (self) but was given (self) as well as the three other values.